# jQuery ajax time without specifically timing it

Tags: jquery, ajax, time

I know I can time my $.ajax calls using something like

```
var ajaxTime= new Date().getTime();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
}).done(function () {
    var totalTime = new Date().getTime()-ajaxTime;
    // Here I want to get the how long it took to load some.php and use it further
 });
```

But, I want to have a generic way of getting the loading time for any $.ajax calls I make, without adding the `Date()` to that specific ajax calls. Is there a way I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this just for debugging purposes?  If so, Fiddler is a great tool for showing exactly how long an ajax call ran for.

Comment: Yes, I am doing this for debugging. Thanks, I'll give the Fiddler a look!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the global events to do it, use the [.ajaxSend()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) handlers

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqXhr, opts) {
    jqXhr._start = new Date().getTime();
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, jqXhr, opts) {
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('Time taken:', opts.url, end - jqXhr._start)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k2CkV/)

Or you can use any network monitoring tools like the network tabs in the developer tools of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this just for debugging purposes? If so, Fiddler is a great tool for showing exactly how long an ajax call ran for